# mongodb puppet module installation fail

Tags: mongodb, centos, puppet

I am trying to install puppet module https://forge.puppet.com/puppet/mongodb

using this code

```
class {'mongodb::server':
    port    => 27018,
    verbose => true,
    auth    => true,
  }

  class {'mongodb::client':}

  mongodb::db { 'xxxxx2':
    user          => 'xxxx',
    password_hash => 'a15fbfca5e3a758be80ceaf42458bcd8', 
    require       => Class['mongodb::server', 'mongodb::client'],
  }
```

and I am getting this error

```
err Puppet  Could not prefetch mongodb_database provider 'mongodb': Could not evaluate MongoDB shell command: rs.slaveOk();printjson(db.getMongo().getDBs())
err Puppet  Failed to apply catalog: Could not evaluate MongoDB shell command: rs.slaveOk();printjson(db.getMongo().getDBs())
```

Any one come across this issue and know any fix?

Ref:
https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-mongodb/issues/464

Answer (score 0):

Changing `auth => true` to `auth => false` remove error.

```
class {'mongodb::server':
    port    => 27018,
    verbose => true,
    auth    => false,
  }

  class {'mongodb::client':}

  mongodb::db { 'xxxxx2':
    user          => 'xxxx',
    password_hash => 'a15fbfca5e3a758be80ceaf42458bcd8', 
    require       => Class['mongodb::server', 'mongodb::client'],
  }
```

> **auth**
>
> > Set to true to enable database authentication for users connecting
> >     from remote hosts. If no users exist, the localhost interface will
> >     continue to have access to the database until you create the first
> >     user. Default: false